# Looking for a Windows emulator accessed via my Linux browser

Tags: windows, emulator

I am using Ubuntu. I keep being asked by friends how to perform simple actions on their Windows PCs. For example, I want to tell them "Go to the start menu then ....". So I need to be able to go to my browser, go to a "live" Windows system or emulator and then explain the actions that I am taking. BrowserStack only lets me work within a test browser rather than the full operating system. I do not need to download / upload files on the test PC or the emulator.

Comment: Hello, why not simply use a virtual machine?